# How do I download a PDF in portrait layout using the Smartsheet api?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

Downloading a Smartsheet as a PDF file is straightforward.
Here's my script:

```
import smartsheet

smartsheet = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token)

sheetId = target_sheet_id
download_directory_path = 'C:\Users\User\Downloads'
paper_size = 'LETTER'

# Download target sheet to specified location as PDF of given size 
smartsheet.Sheets.get_sheet_as_pdf(sheetId, download_directory_path, paper_size)
```

The problem is that the PDF is in landscape mode and more than one page wide.
The Smartsheets I'm trying to download all require portrait mode and fit to one page in order to display properly.

Is there a parameter that I'm missing that would allow me to change the layout to portrait mode and fit to width?

If not, are there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've identified a limitation in the underlying product API. 
I've added a request to be able specify page layout to our product backlog, but can't make any commitments about priority or schedule.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Smartsheet API [documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet-as-excel-/-pdf-/-csv), the API does not currently support being able to specify Orientation when retrieving a Sheet in PDF format. Perhaps you can change orientation after downloading the PDF from Smartsheet, by using something like [PyPDF2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2)?

(It's a couple of years old, but looks like this article contains some good info re tools you can use to manipulate PDFs using Python: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167 -- including some info about **PyPDF2**).